# How could I find the number of movies every two actors had played the below Data Frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a Data Frame:

```
pd.DataFrame({'movie':['HT','TP','Wi','kah','MB'],'actors':[['QQ','AA','ZZ','WW','SS','XX'],['QQ','WW','EE','DD','SS','AA'],['EE','DD','CC','RR','FF','VV'],['VV','CC','XX','ZZ','FF','DD'],['SS','AA','RR','EE','WW','QQ']]})
```

that is a movie DataFrame with all the actors in each movie, I want to find out the number of movies every two actors had played together. e.g. the number of movies the artistic couple 'AA' and 'QQ' had played with each other.

Answer (score 4):

Let's try exploding `actors` then self-merge:

```
s = df.explode('actors')
(s.merge(s, on='movie')
  .query('actors_x<actors_y')
  .groupby(['actors_x','actors_y']).size()
  .unstack('actors_y', fill_value=0)
)
```

Output:

```
actors_y  DD  EE  FF  QQ  RR  SS  VV  WW  XX  ZZ
actors_x                                        
AA         1   2   0   3   1   3   0   3   1   1
CC         2   1   2   0   1   0   2   0   1   1
DD         0   2   2   1   1   1   2   1   1   1
EE         0   0   1   2   2   2   1   2   0   0
FF         0   0   0   0   1   0   2   0   1   1
QQ         0   0   0   0   1   3   0   3   1   1
RR         0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0
SS         0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3   1   1
VV         0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
WW         0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
XX         0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2
```

Comment: Hi, Sorry for my late reply, First of all, your code worked well for this little sample data frame, but unfortunately this didn't satisfy my need. Let me say exactly what I need: 
My real DataFrame has about 3000 rows with real Movie names and actors, I want to find all 2 actors (artistic couples) that have played 7 or more movies together.
Sorry if I wasn't clear at the beginning. I thought I could handle the rest myself but it turned out that I couldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is below. Quang Hong's answer above is probably far faster and more in the spirit of using pandas, but here's another way to do it:

```py
from itertools import combinations, chain
# chain.from_iterable concatenates all of the lists in actors into one list.
# set gets only the unique elements
unique_actors = set(chain.from_iterable(df["actors"]))
num_movies_for_actor_pair = {}

# combinations gets every unique combination of 2 actors
for combination in combinations(unique_actors, 2):
    actor_1 = combination[0]
    actor_2 = combination[1]
    # creates a 1 or 0 binary column for whether the current actor pair was in the movies together,
    # then sums it to get the total number of movies
    num_movies = np.sum(df.apply(lambda row: actor_1 in row["actors"] and actor_2 in row["actors"], axis=1))
    # makes a string of the two actor names to act as a key in the dictionary
    actor_pair = "{},{}".format(actor_1, actor_2)
    # adds the number of movies to the dictionary for this actor pair
    num_movies_for_actor_pair[actor_pair] = num_movies
    
print(num_movies_for_actor_pair)
```